# How to force RPi to wait for data from UART?

Tags: python, uart

Like above: how to force RPi to wait for data from UART and do not terminate the program ?
I solved my problem with connection between RPi and BT Module and Arduino but the program I wrote is closing after receiving one bit.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial import time
import sys
port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=100) BOARD=GPIO.BOARD
OUT=GPIO.OUT
HIGH=GPIO.HIGH
LOW=GPIO.LOW

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, OUT)

port.write('1')

if(port.read() == '1'):
    GPIO.output(11, HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(11, LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
    print "OK"

else:
    print "Fail"
    port.write('0')
```

Comment: It may help to specify what programming or scripting language you are using.

Comment: and include the code

Comment: @albal You have it in tags.

Comment: I don't see code there :P

Comment: Just updated the post.

Comment: `while(port.inWaiting() < 1):` should do.

Answer (score 1):

Use loop

```
while(param):
    whatever_to_do()
```